# InAppBrowser not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, inappbrowser

I am trying to use the inAppBrowser Plugin with Cordova 3.4.1, but unfortunately it doesn't work. My config.xml looks like this:

```
<access origin="*" browserOnly="true"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
```

The inAppBrowser plugin is installed (I can find it in the plugins/ folder). I try to open my links with:

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://www.google.de','_system','location=yes');">test</a>
<a onclick="window.open('http://www.google.de','_blank','location=yes');">test</a>
```

But all links will open in the app itself, not in the system browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser"/>
    </feature>` in your config.xml file!